# hydration failed error using recharts with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recharts

I have just started a new Next project, and I want to use a library called [ReCharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/).

However, whenever I use it in my project, even with one of the provided examples, it throws the following errors:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in `<div>`.

Warning: Prop `y` did not match. Server: "5" Client: "10.800000190734863"
    at text
    at Text (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/recharts/es6/component/Text.js:232:5)
    at g
    at Layer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/recharts/es6/container/Layer.js:23:24)
    at g
    at g
    at Layer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/recharts/es6/container/Layer.js:23:24)
    at CartesianAxis (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/recharts/es6/cartesian/CartesianAxis.js:77:5)
    at svg
    at Surface (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/recharts/es6/container/Surface.js:23:24)
    at div
    at CategoricalChartWrapper (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/recharts/es6/chart/generateCategoricalChart.js:920:7)
    at SimpleBarChart
    at main
    at div
    at Home
```

Here is my code:

```
const data = [
    {
        name: "Page A",
        uv: 4000,
        pv: 2400,
        amt: 2400,
    },
    {
        name: "Page B",
        uv: 3000,
        pv: 1398,
        amt: 2210,
    },
    {
        name: "Page C",
        uv: 2000,
        pv: 9800,
        amt: 2290,
    },
    {
        name: "Page D",
        uv: 2780,
        pv: 3908,
        amt: 2000,
    },
    {
        name: "Page E",
        uv: 1890,
        pv: 4800,
        amt: 2181,
    },
    {
        name: "Page F",
        uv: 2390,
        pv: 3800,
        amt: 2500,
    },
    {
        name: "Page G",
        uv: 3490,
        pv: 4300,
        amt: 2100,
    }
];

function SimpleBarChart(){
    return (
        <BarChart
            id={1}
            width={500}
            height={300}
            data={data}
            margin={{
                top: 5,
                right: 30,
                left: 20,
                bottom: 5,
            }}>
                <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                <XAxis dataKey="name" />
                <YAxis />
                <Tooltip />
                <Legend />
                <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8" />
                <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#82ca9d" />
        </BarChart>
    );
}

export default function Home(){
    return (
        <SimpleBarChart />
    );
}
```

Note that this is copied and pasted in from [here](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SimpleBarChart), so it should really "just work" out of the box.

Comment: You can dynamically import your custom `SimpleBarChart` component on the client-side only using [`{ ssr: false }`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr), this will prevent any hydration issue from occurring.

Answer (score 6):

As @juliomalves says, the answer is to use dynamic imports with `ssr` disabled:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const SimpleBarChartWithoutSSR = dynamic(
    import("../components/rechartsCharts/SimpleBar"),
    { ssr: false }
);
const SimpleScatterChartWithoutSSR = dynamic(
    import("../components/rechartsCharts/SimpleScatter"),
    { ssr: false }
);
const DashedLineChartWithoutSSR = dynamic(
    import("../components/rechartsCharts/DashedLine"),
    { ssr: false }
);
const PercentAreaChartWithoutSSR = dynamic(
    import("../components/rechartsCharts/PercentArea"),
    { ssr: false }
);
```

Comment: it wouldn't hurt to explain why this works

Comment: ```
Type '{ children: Element[]; width: number; height: number; data: daysDownloads[]; margin: { top: number; right: number; bottom: number; left: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'
```

It works, but I get this error in VS code

Answer (score 2):

For those struggling with rendering the `Pie` chart using @plutownium's answer, you *need* to use a hybrid of dynamic imports with `ssr` disabled and regular importing:

```
import { Pie, Cell } from "recharts";

const PieChart = dynamic(() => (
    import("recharts").then(recharts => recharts.PieChart)
), { ssr: false });

const Example = () => (
    <PieChart width={100} height={100}>
        <Pie data={data} {/* etc... */}>
            { data.map(entry => (
                <Cell fill={entry.color} key={entry.key} />
            ))}
        </Pie>
    </PieChart>
);
```

This should prevent hydration warnings *and* allow the chart to render.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It solves my problem

```
const LineChart = dynamic(() => import('recharts').then(mod => mod.LineChart), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest setup is to have a custom client component that does all the Recharts rendering and then to just load that component (and only that one) dynamically with SSR off.

Please note that, in one of the answers, `dynamic()` is called without defining a function for the first argument. That does not seem to work. (See also the documentation at https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading for examples.) Also note that adding `.then()` after `import()` is only needed if there is no default export that can be used.

Here is a sample server component that uses a chart rendered by a component called `SimpleBars`:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const SimpleBars = dynamic(() => import('./bars-test'), { ssr: false })
export default function ChartSection() {
  return (
    <section>
      <SimpleBars />
    </section>
  )
}
```

And here is the `SimpleBars` component (in a file named `bars-test.jsx`):

```js
'use client'
import { BarChart, Bar } from 'recharts'
const data = [
  {name: 'Category 1', series1: 400},
  {name: 'Category 2', series1: 200},
  {name: 'Category 3', series1: 500},
  {name: 'Category 4', series1: 100},
]
export default function BarsTest() {
  return (
    <BarChart width={500} height={400} data={data}>
      <Bar dataKey="series1" fill="#bcbcbc" />
    </BarChart>
  )
}
```

On the server side, this will be rendered as the following HTML, and the chart will then be drawn on the client side, without any hydration errors. This was tested with Next.js 14.0.3 and Recharts 2.9.3.

```html
<section>
  <template data-dgst="NEXT_DYNAMIC_NO_SSR_CODE" data-msg="NEXT_DYNAMIC_NO_SSR_CODE"></template>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

use the following to ensure Client-Side Rendering:

```
const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true);
  }, []);
```